# Impl trait method on generic and vec of generic within a struct

Tags: generics, rust, struct, traits, implements

I'm trying to implement the approx crate traits for a struct and it's fine with the values that are f64, but I don't know how to implement for the Vec values.

The struct is

```rust
pub struct Body<T> {
    pub id: u8,
    pub label: String,
    pub mass: T,
    pub pos: Vec<T>,
    pub vel: Vec<T>,
    pub obj_col: T,
}
```

I've used generics in the struct as the crate instructions use generics, but everywhere that is T I know will be f64.

An example of the first impl block

```rust
impl<T: approx::AbsDiffEq> approx::AbsDiffEq for Body<T> where
    T::Epsilon: Copy,
{
    type Epsilon = T::Epsilon;

    fn default_epsilon() -> T::Epsilon {
        T::default_epsilon()
    }

    fn abs_diff_eq(&self, other: &Self, epsilon: T::Epsilon) -> bool {
        T::abs_diff_eq(&self.mass, &other.mass, epsilon) &&
        T::abs_diff_eq(&self.pos, &other.pos, epsilon)
    }
}
```

Basically it throws errors at the references to pos. The error states it is because mismatched types, expecting &T and getting &Vec. I understand that it's an unexpected type but I don't know how to solve it. I'm still relatively new to rust.

Also if it's possible to implement this on the concrete type f64 instead that would be good.

Edit: I've worked around the problem by implementing PartialEq on the struct and then using approx crate only on the field I need it for.

Comment: Iterate over the `Vec`, and compare each item?

Comment: Would I have to define a new abs_diff_eq function for vecs? Or can I do that inside the same func?

Comment: It's a shame [`Iterator::eq_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq_by) is unstable, because it would be a great way to solve this problem.

Comment: Just do: `self.pos.iter().zip (other.iter()).all (|(x, y) T::abs_diff_eq (x, y, epsilon))`

Comment: Or just use a `for` loop: `for us, them in other.pos.iter().zip(self.pos.iter()) { if !T::abs_diff_eq(us, them, epsilon) { return false; } }`

Comment: But why are you even bothering with generics if you don't need them? What's wrong with just using `f64` in `pub struct Body`, and implementing traits simply with `impl AbsDiffEq for Body { type Epsilon = f64; /* or <f64 as AbsDiffEq>::Epsilon if you want to be fancy */ ... }`, etc? That should work, and be much simpler if you *don't* actually require a generic `T`.

Comment: @user4815162342 the simple answer to that is I didn't know how

Comment: @thefrollickingnerd Does my comment actually help with that, or do you still don't know how to do that (or have given up)? If it's helpful, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @user4815162342 Your comment is very useful in that it's helped me understand rust better but I've found a different solution to the problem and think that suits my needs.

Comment: Good to hear - have fun with Rust!